# How do I stop a program on AmazonAWS?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rack, padrino

I am using AmazonAWS server to run my application. To start the application I am using:

```
RACK_BASE_URI=/project bundle exec rackup -D
```

To stop the application I am using:

```
ps -ef|grep <port>
pkill <pid>
```

Even then the application is running. Can anyone tell me how to stop the application?

Comment: `kill -9 <pid>` doesn't work either?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev it too not working.. i tried...

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev any other ways to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `top` and then `kill <pid>` the ruby process

Comment: The first and second comments to the question says that `kill -9 <pid>` didn't work. Why would `kill <pid>` work without the `kill` signal? `9 = KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)`